# Beginner's questions about Matplotlib OO Api

Tags: matplotlib

I am new to Matplotlib and am struggling a bit to differentiate between the OO and pyplot interfaces.  I’m actually working with the Kivy GUI framework and trying to plot 4 subplots on a single figure, to be displayed by Kivy.  Here’s a snippet of my code:

```
def create_plot(self):

    self.fig, ((self.ax0, self.ax1), (self.ax2, self.ax3)) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2)

    self.ax0.set_title("A")
    self.ax0.grid(True, lw = 2, ls = '--', c = '.75')

    self.ax1.set_title("B")
    self.ax1.grid(True, lw = 2, ls = '--', c = '.75')

    self.ax2.set_title("C")
    self.ax2.grid(True, lw = 2, ls = '--', c = '.75')

    self.ax3.set_title("D")
    self.ax3.grid(True, lw = 2, ls = '--', c = '.75')

    #plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()

    canvas = self.fig.canvas
    self.add_widget(canvas)
```

What worries me is that I am calling plt methods and assigning the results to my objects.  Is plt the state machine interface and not the OO interface, or is this OK?

Secondly, I want to periodically update the plotted lines, so I have a plot method that does this:

```
def plot(self,  xCoords, yCoords):

    if len(self.ax0.lines) > 0:
        self.ax0.lines.pop(0)

    line = self.ax0.plot(xCoords, yCoords, color='blue')

    canvas = self.fig.canvas
    canvas.draw()
```

Does that look ok?  Can I just pop the existing line, or should I reuse the existing line?

Lastly, and most difficult, if I enable:

```
plt.tight_layout()
```

I get an exception:

```
C:\Kivy-1.9.0-py3.4-win32-x64\Python34\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\tight_layout.py:225: UserWarning: tight_layout : falling back to Agg renderer
   warnings.warn("tight_layout : falling back to Agg renderer")
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "main.py", line 1117, in <module>
     GuiApp().run()
   File "C:\Kivy-1.9.0-py3.4-win32-x64\Python34\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 801, in run
     self.load_kv(filename=self.kv_file)
   File "C:\Kivy-1.9.0-py3.4-win32-x64\Python34\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 598, in load_kv
     root = Builder.load_file(rfilename)
   File "C:\Kivy-1.9.0-py3.4-win32-x64\Python34\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang.py", line 1801, in load_file
     return self.load_string(data, **kwargs)
   File "C:\Kivy-1.9.0-py3.4-win32-x64\Python34\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang.py", line 1880, in load_string
     self._apply_rule(widget, parser.root, parser.root)
   File "C:\Kivy-1.9.0-py3.4-win32-x64\Python34\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang.py", line 2038, in _apply_rule
     self._apply_rule(child, crule, rootrule)
   File "C:\Kivy-1.9.0-py3.4-win32-x64\Python34\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang.py", line 2037, in _apply_rule
     self.apply(child)
   File "C:\Kivy-1.9.0-py3.4-win32-x64\Python34\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang.py", line 1924, in apply
     self._apply_rule(widget, rule, rule)
   File "C:\Kivy-1.9.0-py3.4-win32-x64\Python34\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang.py", line 2038, in _apply_rule
     self._apply_rule(child, crule, rootrule)
   File "C:\Kivy-1.9.0-py3.4-win32-x64\Python34\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang.py", line 2038, in _apply_rule
     self._apply_rule(child, crule, rootrule)
   File "C:\Kivy-1.9.0-py3.4-win32-x64\Python34\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang.py", line 2035, in _apply_rule
     child = cls(__no_builder=True)
   File "C:\SVNProj\Raggio\trunk\hostconsole\gui\mygraph.py", line 127, in __init__
     self.create_plot()
   File "C:\SVNProj\Raggio\trunk\hostconsole\gui\mygraph.py", line 224, in create_plot
     self.add_widget(canvas)
   File "C:\Kivy-1.9.0-py3.4-win32-x64\Python34\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\boxlayout.py", line 211, in add_widget
     widget.bind(
 AttributeError: 'FigureCanvasAgg' object has no attribute 'bind'
```

Can anyone help with that please?

Best regards

David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Original post

1. regarding `def create_plot`

`plt.subplots()` is just a wrapper around creating a new figure and adding subplots (axes) to that figure, so that is safe to use in any context AFAIK

2. regarding updating lines vs creating new lines.

Popping off and creating a new line with a call to `axes.plot()` will work, but will be slower than just using the existing line artist and calling `artist.set_data(x_data, y_data)`

3. Regarding the `tight_layout` issue

Consider just calling `self.fig.tight_layout()` instead of `plt.tight_layout()`, as `plt.tight_layout()` might be grabbing the wrong figure

### Update based on discussion in comments:

Since you are plotting one line per panel, I would suggest adding these four lines to your `create_plot` method to save the LineArtist's that are created by the axes.plot() method:

```
self.line0, = self.ax0.plot([], [], 'b')
self.line1, = self.ax1.plot([], [], 'b')
self.line2, = self.ax2.plot([], [], 'b')
self.line3, = self.ax3.plot([], [], 'b')
```

Then in the `plot` method you can just do this:

```
self.line0.set_data(xCoords, yCoords)
```

Though I seem to be struggling to remember how to make `ax0` automatically update its limits based on the `xCoords` and `yCoords`.  I thought that it was as simple as `self.ax0.relim()`, but that is not working in my jupyter notebook right now. Hmm.

Comment: Thanks for your answers.  For (2) how can I get hold of the line object owned by an axis object (so that I can set its data)?  For (3) I'm afraid I still get the same error with self.fig.tight_layout().

Comment: (2) Are you plotting more than one line per axes?
(3) I would suggest asking the kivy mailing list. I have not used the Kivy framework before, sorry!  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/kivy-users

Comment: Only one line per axis. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Updated original comment to illustrate how you would save the line object. Sorry I was not helpful re: Kivy